# Bootstrap - carousel slides activated from navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, navbar

Do you know if its possible to make the Bootstrap carousel slides to be controled from a nav bar and not only from the default carousel indicators?

And how? :P

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it's possible if you code it.

Comment: :) now its all clear thanks for the smart answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel should explain it sufficiently.

To get you started:

`$('#btn-in-nav-bar').click(function () {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel('prev');
  //Or $('#myCarousel').carousel('next') if it's a next button
});`